# is it good to store solr data in hdfs in production system?

Tags: hadoop, solr

I am using solr 4.x with hadoop cluster. Crawled data in stored in hadoop and indexed in solr. Currently solr is configured to use local file system. I have to go to production . Is it good to use local file system or should use hdfs for solr? What are the benefits of using hdfs (if we have to use)?
In future it is possible that my index size will increase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only benefit is replication and horizontal scalability.

Comment: if my index size become too large then is it good to use hdfs (with multiple nodes) or simply add a new hard disk ?

Comment: If your index size is too large, then you can use sharding in SOLR to split the index across various cores.